# Hello, first question on here. I've been trying to put a image in my website but it isn't working and I just can't figure out the reason. My code HTML

Tags: html, replit

```
    <body style="background-color:#23272A;" <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1wzC2IUozmJdeX6WlL3hP40e2V5xRm3AH" alt="Bling logo"
 width="190" height="120">
    <hr>
    <h1>bert is corn</h1>
    <hr>
```

With the code I am trying to display a logo to represent the website. The code here only involves the logo. Please help if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

First, a typo. You forgot to end the `<body` start tag with a `>`.

Second: The value of the `src` attribute has to be a URL pointing to an image.

The URL you are using points to an HTML document.

---

Google Drive is a file storage service, not a web hosting service. It isn't designed for your purposes. Find somewhere else to store your image files.

Answer (score 1):

this is a very basic error, you forgot to close the  tag.

```
<body style="background-color:#23272A;"> <img ......
---------------------------------------↑
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the `<body>` tag

```
<body style="background-color:#23272A;">
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1wzC2IUozmJdeX6WlL3hP40e2V5xRm3AH" alt="Bling logo"
 width="190" height="120">
    <hr>
    <h1>bert is corn</h1>
    <hr>
```

Comment: Maybe I worded that wrong... not the closing tag.... the <body> element is missing its >

Comment: I must've deleted the closing tag while changing the background. Thank you this helped.

Comment: Glad it helped, remember to upvote useful answers.